# crankset compatability

Tags: shimano, crankset

I am wondering if I would be able to run the 105 5800 crankset with my 9 speed ultegra 5600 shifters/rd?  I don't have the funds to do the whole groupset at once, and I believe upgrading to 11 speed would also mean that I need to get a new rear wheel.

Some more info / related questions:  I have an 05 roubaix that has Ultegra 5600 Brakes/shifters and cassette/RD, and an fsa gossamer 52/39 crankset.  the front derailleur has 3 positions although I just have 2 chainrings.  the front derailleur shifts pretty terribly and the chain drops frequently when i shift down.  do most front derailleurs have 3 positions even when there are only 2 chainrings?  I set it up so that I can use the middle position to get away with some cross-chaining, but should I be doing this at all?

Comment: Correctly set-up Shimano front shifters have 4 positions, two very close together on each chainring for trimming purposes. When you fully shift to the bigger ring and just touch the lever afterwards the front derailleur moves a tiny bit to the inside. Same on the lower ring where a slight upshifting movement will bring the derailleur a tiny bit away from the inside position. This lets you adjust the postion when the chain rubs on the derailleur plates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

11 speed chain rings will be slightly narrower than 9 speed. So they will work, but it's not an ideal pairing. You should be able to keep your rear wheel and replace the 9 speed cassette with an 11. The dropout width hasn't changes, the gears have just got thinner.

Not sure what you mean by front derailleur having 3 positions. It swings through a fixed distance, it is the shifter that determines if there are 2 or 3 indexed points to stop at. A 3 speed shifter isn't going to work well with a 2 speed chain ring. But you try adjusting the lower limit screw to stop the chain dropping.